# How To Disable Nagle on iOS POSIX Socket

Tags: ios, c, sockets, tcp, posix

I'll start by saying that I definitely want to disable Nagle's Algorithm. The application that I am testing for is a real time P2P app in which packets are small and extremely time sensitive. This test also serves to compare UDP and TCP for possible networking solutions.

I am able to open the TCP socket and send messages back and forth, but I have not been able to disable Nagle's Algorithm. I have tried:

```
static const int yes = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &yes, sizeof(yes))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting tcp nodelay\n");
    return -2;
}
```

on both the listening and connecting sockets. This does not fail. I also elevated the priority of the receiving thread to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH.

The test I am running starts with a packet that contains "start", followed by numerous packets that contain "data" and one final packet containing "stop". These packets are almost always combined into one or few packets, such as:

Received Peer Message: startdatadatadatadatadatadatastop

or

Received Peer Message: startdatadatadata
Received Peer Message: datadatadatastop

Is there a difference in the way that TCP_NODELAY is set on iOS? I was able to set it on Linux with the above code successfully.

Comment: try with new line added after the commands like. `start\n`, `data\n`, `stop\n` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but that just results in the messages being split by newlines; it's still received as one or two messages.

Comment: I trust you are using a packet sniffer (such as Wireshark) to determine that sends are being combined (and therefore Nagle has not been disabled), and not relying on what is contained in each read.

Comment: if the 'small' packets must make it through and make it through in the correct order, then UDP will not work for your application, unless you want to implement a packet timeout, a retry, and have each packet labeled as to its' location in the overall data.  This is a messy procedure.  it is much easier to use TCP and it handles all those details for you.

Comment: you might want to read: <http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-ip-options-for-high-performance-data-transmission/> (much too long to post here)  as it discusses the TCP_NODELAY socket option and what it actually does.

Comment: per this site: <msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/…; TCP_NODELAY expects a unsigned long int with a boolean value. Enables or disables the Nagle algorithm for TCP sockets. This option is disabled (set to FALSE) by default.  suggest: unsigned long int yes = (unsigned long int)TRUE;

Comment: @TonyB Good idea. I'm testing the app directly on iOS so I didn't think that it would be possible to trace packets, but it looks like OSX is able to do it on the iOS device through USB. I'll try that and see if Nagle is indeed being used

Comment: @user3629249 I don't believe that the order matters for the packets, they are all accompanied by a timestamp. The app must also use some sort of hole punching for NATs, that's why UDP is being considered